# SQL Using COUNT

Tags: sql

I'm doing past papers for my database exam, and I've come across the following question:

---

Given the schema:

- **Station**(name, city) (name is key)
- **Train**(number, day, depart_station, arrive_station, depart_time, arrive_time) (number and day are a composite key, and day in {Monday, Tuesday, ... , Sunday}.
- **Service**(train number, train_type, food_served, first_class) (train_number is key and first_class is "yes" or "no".

The query is:

Find stations from which at least 20 trains with first-class service depart for Edinburgh every week on weekdays.

My answer to this is:

```
WITH fstClass AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Train T, Service S
    WHERE T.number = S.train_number AND T.arrive_station = "Edinburgh" 
    AND S.first_class = 'yes'
    AND T.day LIKE 'S%'
    )
SELECT f.depart_station
FROM fstclass f
GROUP by f.depart_airport
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

I'm debating with my friend whether this is right, and I personally don't see what could be wrong with it. So any insight on whether this seems correct and/or better ways about doing this query would be much appreciated. Are temporary tables a good way to do SQL queries?

Comment: In my opinion, any query that has a comma in the `from` clause is automatically wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Service` table? What is its relationship with `Train`? Can a single `Train` have multiple `Service` rows? What does it mean if multiple `Service` rows with the same data for the same parent `Train` row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff how would you suggest I apporach this? If instead of `FROM Train T, Station S`, I use `FROM Train T JOIN Station S ON T.number = S.train_number` would that be more correct for you? :)

Comment: @Dai I goofed up writing my original query. `Service` is used to check if the train provdes a first class service - so that also explains its relationship, A train cannot have multiple service rows AFAIK. The only data we are provided for this relation is the one mentioned in the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: I always love it when homework questions get posted with a disclaimer: *Note: This isn't homework. I did this assignment months ago, but I've forgotten whether I passed it or not. Can someone answer these questions for me so I can compare it with what I turned in to see if I got it right?*

Comment: @KenWhite but this isn't homework, if you like I can happily link you to the past paper that has a date of May 2012 :). The fact that we're in the month of May might suggest that for many, inlcuding me, it's examination period. Don't be so condescending.

Comment: @user3186023 Then the `Service` data is a denormalization that should be removed. Columns from `Service` should be moved into the `Trains` table, so your schema only needs 2 tables: `Stations` and `Trains`, and given that `Station` value data is already in the `Trains` table you only need 1 table.

Comment: @Dai that's true, but as unfortunate as it is, in this question I'm not free to make any changes to the schema provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery can be eliminated, and `HAVING` used:

```
SELECT
    Trains.departingStation,
    COUNT(*) AS numberOfTrains
FROM
    Trains
    INNER JOIN Services ON Trains.number = Services.number
WHERE
    arrivalStation = 'Edinburgh'
    AND
    Services.hasFirstClassService = 1
    AND
    day NOT IN ( 'Saturday', 'Sunday' )
GROUP BY
    departingStation
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 20
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there anything wrong with my original query that sticks out to you though?

Comment: `column-alias` in the `where` clause?

Comment: Semantically your query is largely the same as mine, except you aliased the subquery with a `WITH` clause (known as a Common Table Expression). It works, but it's syntactically unnecessarily complicated. Also avoid commas in `FROM` clauses like the plague: always prefer explicit `JOIN`s.

Comment: @user3186023 I have simplified my query.

Comment: Thanks for these tips, will bare this in mind for my exam tomorrow :)